# Will Google charge me if I add another domain on my grandfathered Google Apps account?

Tags: gmail, google-workspace, domain

My Google Apps Free Edition account was grandfathered in before Google discontinued the creation of new accounts of this type.  Businesses that want Google-based email to be associated with their domain name (ex: web@mybusinessdomainname.com) must open a Google Apps for Business account, and Google charges money for this.

My question is: I just recently started up another web domain and would like to add that as a domain-alias on my grandfathered account. Will Google charge me for this?

Comment: Did you ever find out the answer?

Comment: I've heard that you can add another domain and it still falls under the grandfathered plans

Answer (score 1):

No, you can add multiple domain alias' or sub domains to this account and you will not be charged. You will be restricted to 10 user licences but you can work around this by adding email alias' to existing email accounts

Comment: Do you have any evidence of this?